# Laravel 8 returns two different folders for the same path

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 8.35.1 and try to check if a folder exists or - if not - create it.
The paths are:

- `data/4d61c171-cd94-48ec-82bb-8fee7394471a/processor/333afcbc-37be-4e19-bddc-605c21e766bb`
- `data/4d61c171-cd94-48ec-82bb-8fee7394471a/downloads/333afcbc-37be-4e19-bddc-605c21e766bb`

The folders should be created in `storage/app/`.

I do the same for both paths:

```
$processFolder = $fileHelper->existOrCreate('data/4d61c171-cd94-48ec-82bb-8fee7394471a/processor/333afcbc-37be-4e19-bddc-605c21e766bb');
$downloadFolder = $fileHelper->existOrCreate('data/4d61c171-cd94-48ec-82bb-8fee7394471a/downloads/333afcbc-37be-4e19-bddc-605c21e766bb');


public function existOrCreate($path)
{
    if (!File::exists($path)) {
        if (!File::makeDirectory($path, 0755, true)) {
            send_error_mail('Folder could not be created: ' . $path);
        }
    }

    return $path;
}
```

The problem is, that always the downloads folder is wrongly created in

```
/public/data/4d61c171-cd94-48ec-82bb-8fee7394471a/downloads/333afcbc-37be-4e19-bddc-605c21e766bb
```

and the processor folder is correctly created in

```
/storage/app/data/4d61c171-cd94-48ec-82bb-8fee7394471a/processor/333afcbc-37be-4e19-bddc-605c21e766bb
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Storage` facade instead of the `File` facade.

Comment: There's the same problem! When I run Storage::disk('local')->exists(.....) it also returns me true - the same as File::exists...